# Initial FIDE rating below floor, what happens?

Tags: tournament, rating, fide, elo, otb-chess

I'm curious to know what happens in the following scenario:

I play a Swiss tournament and meet 3 rated players, I score at least half point but do badly overall. Then I play another Swiss tournament and meet another 3 rated players and do better this time.

Overall, my initial rating is below the rating floor of 1000 because of how badly I played against the first 3 rated players, and rating is not published.

My questions are:

1. Are my first 6 results discarded and I have to play 5 new rated opponents?
2. If yes to (1), do I have to score at least half a point in a tournament again before my results are considered for my initial rating?
3. If no to (1), are all of my first 6 results kept, forcing me to keep playing until I have pooled enough results to be above the floor of 1000 within 26 months?

Follow up scenario:

Assume the same thing happens as above, but I played 3 rated players in my first tournament and 6 in the second. My performance in the first one is terrible, but I did well in the second. If you pooled all 9 games, my rating would be below the floor, but if you only looked at my last 6 games, my rating would be above the floor.

What happens in this case?

Answer (score 7):

The rules FIDE use in calculating a player's first rating are outlined in the [FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 July 2017](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022017).

The relevant sections are:

> 6.1 If an unrated player scores zero in his first tournament, his score and that of his opponents against him are disregarded. Otherwise if an unrated player has played rated games, then this result is included in computing his overall rating

and

> 7.14 A rating for a player new to the list shall be published only if it meets the following criteria:
>
> 7.14a If based on results obtained under 6.3, a minimum of 5 games.
>
> 7.14b If based on results obtained under 6.4, a minimum of 5 games played against rated opponents.
>
> 7.14c The condition of a minimum of 5 games need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments played within consecutive rating periods of not more than 26 months are pooled to obtain the initial rating.
>
> 7.14d The rating is at least 1000.
>
> 7.14e **The rating is calculated using all his results as if they were played in one tournament** (it is not published until he has played at least 5 games) by using all the rating data available.

So, the answers to your questions are clear:

> 1. Are my first 6 results discarded and I have to play 5 new rated
>    opponents?

Since you scored more than zero in your first tournament then all the results will be used in calculating your rating provided they were played within a 26 month window. So, provided 26 months have not elapsed then the answer is "No".

> 2. If yes to (1), do I have to score at least half a point in a
>    tournament again before my results are considered for my initial
>    rating?

If your next tournament was more than 26 months after the first two (i.e. "yes to (1)) then that counts as your first tournament and the rule regarding scoring zero in your first tournament applies.

> 3. If no to (1), are all of my first 6 results kept, forcing me to keep
>    playing until I have pooled enough results to be above the floor of
>    1000 within 26 months?

According to 7.14e the answer is yes with the 26 month proviso. Every time an old tournament drops out of the 26 month window it is excluded from your results.